# Why do I have value is borrowed in closure error?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand closures in Rust and why I am getting a "borrow error" in my code.

I thought that `i32` is stored in stack memory and shouldn't have borrow-related errors.
Am I missing something?

My code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut outer_var = 42;

    let closure_annotated = |i: i32| -> i32 { i + outer_var };
    println!("closure_annotated: {}", closure_annotated(1));
    outer_var *= 100; // cannot assign to `outer_var` because it is borrowed in closure
    println!("closure_annotated2: {}", closure_annotated(1));
}
```

Comment: Whether something is on the stack or not has no bearing on Rust's borrowing rules. What do you expect the second call of the closure to print? 43 or 421?

Comment: I don't understand error reason. I would expect 421

Answer (score 3):

The problem in this case is that the closure implicitly created an immutable reference to `outer_var`, since you read it in the closure body. The reference has to be valid up to last use of the closure. What you are doing violates the borrowing rule (multiple immutable or one mutable).

This approach does not work in Rust because a shared reference (immutable borrow) exists to the data you are trying to modify. Rust could re-borrow implicitly but that kind of goes against the general mantra. To further explain what is happening under the hood, see what compiler actually transpiles your code to (more like somewhere along the lines):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut outer_var = 42;

    let closure_state = &outer_var;
    fn closure_function(state: &i32, i: i32) -> i32 {
        *state + i
    }

    println!("closure_annotated: {}", closure_function(closure_state, 1));
    outer_var *= 100; // cannot assign to `outer_var` because it is borrowed in closure
    println!("closure_annotated2: {}", closure_function(closure_state, 1));
}
```